# why is that I can push to the remote without user authentication

Tags: github

I have created a test repo on my github account. It is private. For some reason when I clone the github repo, I can push to the remote without user authentication. How come ?

Comment: Are you sure your authentication isn't saved?

Comment: Actually, I'm using 2 different laptops to test this. I use the first laptop to create the repo and the second one to push. How can I check if my authentication is saved ?

Comment: When you clone it, you enter username and stuff, which is getting stored when you push afterwards.

Comment: It never asked me for the username and password when I clone.

Answer (score 1):

First, check the kind of URL you are using when cloning your private repository: HTTPS or SSH from your second computer.

- HTTPS: your second computer might have already cached your GitHub credentials (for example, on Windows, in the [Windows Credential Manager](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows), but it exists also for [Linux or Mac](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux))
- SSH: you might have [registered your key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account), which would then be enough to authenticate you.